# Light Presets .exr

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, scene, .exr

I would like to install light presets for Blender to automate my lightning in my scenes. I have some .exr files (from Greyscalegorilla) but I don't know how to do it on Blender to make it work. Can someone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can install additional environment lights from the preferences:

[image]

after files are chosen:

[image]

You can now selected them as new environment maps:

[image]

Comment: Sweet, I didn't realize I can add new HDRIs this way :)

Answer (score 0):

Greyscale Gorilla Presets are made with C4D Lights and Image textures. What you can do is use the EXR Files, which are HDRI's, under the "World" to light a Scene. Check this video from Blender Official Channel for more information on World Enviroment: https://youtu.be/RRilLLyyn1Y?t=98